# Jquery error on click slide down

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink, onclick

I am trying to get a box to drop down on the click of a link.
This is my JS function

```
<script language = 'javascript'>
      function toggleInteractlogin(x)
               {
    if($('#' + x).is(":hidden"))
    {
       $('#'+x).slideDown(200);
      }
      else
     {
    $('#'+x).hide();
    }
    $('Interactlogin').hide();


    }
    </script>
```

Whenever i click on the actual link itself nothing slides down.

```
 <div class='buttons'><a href  = '#' onclick = "return false" onmousedown =         "javascripttoggleInteractlogin('login')"class='regular' name='save'> Log In </div></a>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there should be a : between javascript and function name as below

```
javascript:toggleInteractlogin('login');
```

Answer (score 0):

`</div>` is closed in wrong position

### EDIT:

Change this html

```
<div class='buttons'><a href  = '#' onclick = "return false" onmousedown =         "javascripttoggleInteractlogin('login')"class='regular' name='save'> Log In </div></a>
```

to this html

```
<div class='buttons'>
    <a href='#' onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascripttoggleInteractlogin('login')" class='regular' name='save'>Log In</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what you mean?