# Javascript functions overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, function

I have two functions that happen when a link is clicked, a box drops down.

```
<div class='buttons'><a href  = '#' onclick = "return false" onmousedown =     "javascript:toggleInteractlogin('login')"class='regular' name='save'> Log In </div></a>
<div class='buttons'><a href  = '#'  onclick = "return false" onmousedown =     "javascript:toggleInteractlogin('register')" class='regular' name='save'>            Register</div></a><br><br>
<div class = "Interactlogin" id = "login"> Login</div>
<div class = "Interactlogin" id = "register"> Logina</div>
```

When login is clicked, the log in box slides down, but then when the register box is clicked, the login box slides further to accommodate for the register box whereas i would like only one box to be shown at a time.
Any help is appreciated.

```
function toggleInteractlogin(x)
   {
   if($('#' + x).is(":hidden"))
   {
   $('#'+x).slideDown(200);
   }
   else
   {
   $('#'+x).hide();
   }
   $('Interactlogin').hide();


   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366726/jquery-error-on-click-slide-down

Comment: im asking a different question

Comment: Just add code to hide the login box when the register box is clicked, and vice versa. You should consider moving your handlers to jQuery instead of inline.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet for "toggleInteractlogin". My guess is that you just need to make sure that you reset the active box to its default state before you toggle the next box.

Comment: `$('Interactlogin')` should be `$('.Interactlogin')` because you're selecting a class

Comment: Your markup is invalid with the `</a>` outside the div

Answer (score 0):

make sure you slide up the register box first when login button is clicked, similarly make sure you slide up the login button first when when register button is clicked
so for loginn button click

## 1 slide up the register box

## 2 then slide down the login box

similarly for register

## 1 slide up the login box

## 2 then slide down the register box.

try specifying different ids to  login & register button

```
function toggleInteractlogin(x)
   {
     if(x=='register')
        {
            $('#login').hide();
            $('#register').show();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#register').hide();
            $('#login').show();
        }
   }
```

for show/hide you can specify different effect as well like fadein/fadeout

Comment: how would i do this with the function i have

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the solution in **[LIVE DEMO - JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/tSF3p/)**

### HTML

```
<div class='buttons'>
    <a id="btnlogin" href= '#' class='login' name='save'>Log In </a>
</div>
<div class='buttons'>
    <a id="btnregister" href='#' class='regular' name='save'>Register</a>
</div><br><br>

<div class="Interactlogin" id="login" style="display:none">Login</div>
<div class="Interactlogin" id="register" style="display:none">Logina</div>​
```

### JS

```
    $('#btnlogin').click(function(){
        $('#login').show();
        $('#register').hide();
    });
    $('#btnregister').click(function(){
        $('#login').hide();
        $('#register').show();
    });    

​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this a bit using this revised markup:

```
<div class='buttons'><a href='#' class='login'>Log In</a></div>
<div class='buttons'><a href='#' class='register'>Register</a></div>
<br><br> 
<div class = "Interactlogin" id = "login">Login</div>
<div class = "Interactlogin" id = "register">Logina</div>

$('.login,.register').mousedown(function() {
    $('.Interactlogin').hide();//hide them all initially
    var myType = $(this).attr('class');//assumption this is the only class
    $('#' + myType).slideDown(200);
});
```

I assume this CSS to hide initially:(yours may differ)

```
.Interactlogin{display:none;}
```